# Start-Parallel module is not executing a function block when scriptblock option is provided

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

Trying to user start-parallel module but receiving not output. While debugging I could see that it goes to that line but never enter function that I have provided

I have tried using a script block and as a function as well. Went through example provided for Start-parallel module but no result. Be is a script block or a function it showcases a bar that executing two tasks but nothing gets executed

```
Function avolume{
            param ($SCID_server_profile)
            #foreach ($SCID_server_profile in $SCID_JSON.serverProfile)
                #{
                    if ($SCID_server_profile.spdefName -like "spdef_workload*")
                    {
                        #---------------------------------
                        #Getting Server Profile Details
                        #---------------------------------
                        $SCID_frame_number = $SCID_server_profile.synergyFrame
                        $SCID_bay_number = $SCID_server_profile.bayNumber
                        $OV_server_profile_uri = (Get-HPOVServer -Name "$SCID_frame_number, Bay $SCID_bay_number").serverProfileUri

                        if ($OV_server_profile_uri)
                        {
                            $OV_server_profile = Send-HPOVRequest -uri $OV_server_profile_uri
                            $result = Add-SanVolume -ServerProfile $SCID_server_profile -serverprofileobj $OV_server_profile
                            Report-Row -reportwriter $reportwriter -category $result.category -status $result.status -description $result.description
                            if($result.status -eq "fail")
                            {
                                $Script:status = $false
                            }
                            else{$Successful_Configs += 1}
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Report-Row -reportwriter $reportwriter -category "Update Server Profile" -status "Fail" -description "Server Profile does not exist for $SCID_frame_number, $SCID_frame_number"
                            $Script:status = $false
                        }
                    }
                #}
            }
            #$SCID_JSON.serverProfile | Start-Parallel -ScriptBlock $Script
            #Start-Parallel -InputObject $SCID_JSON.serverProfile -ScriptBlock $Script
            $SCID_JSON.serverProfile | Start-Parallel -Scriptblock ${Function:\avolume}
```

I am expecting that whatever is in function should get executed in parallel for values that I am providing

Comment: Is start-parallel similar to [start-job](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821518) where you have to call *-job methods to get responses back?

Comment: Not sure internally what start-parallel is using